# UICollection View Cell is mixing up when i scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am having a problem with cells in a UICollectionView where images are mixing up when scrolling up or down. It will mix up and then stay mixed up, or it will go back to the correct order.

```
class booksVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    var imageIdsonDB : [String] = []
    var imageIds : [String] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var posts = [Post]()
    let db : DBHelper = DBHelper()
    var arrayBooks = [BookModel]()
    var selectedIndexPath : IndexPath = IndexPath()
    var post: Post!

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        adjustViewLayout(size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        for item in self.db.fetchAll() {
            imageIdsonDB.append(item.id)
        }

        self.arrayBooks.removeAll()
        self.arrayBooks.append(contentsOf: self.db.fetchAll())
        self.collectionView.reloadData()

        DataService.ds.REF_POSTS8.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                for snap in snapshot {
                    print ("SNAP: \(snap)")
                    if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                        let key = snap.key
                        let post = Post(postKey: key , postData: postDict)
                        self.posts.append(post)
                        self.db.insertBook(id: postDict["id"] as! String, imgName: postDict["id"] as! String, imgPath: "", bookName: postDict["book_name"] as! String, bookPath: "", imageURL: postDict["image_path"] as! String, bookURL: postDict["book_path"] as! String, caption: "")
                    }
                }
            }
            self.arrayBooks.removeAll()
            self.arrayBooks.append(contentsOf: self.db.fetchAll())
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        })
        // update db for changed database data
        for image in self.db.fetchAll() {
            if !self.imageIds.contains(image.id) {
                self.db.deleteBook(id: image.id)
            }
        }
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    func getFilePath(name : String) -> String {
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let filePath = documentsPath+"/"+name
        return filePath
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayBooks.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let book = arrayBooks[indexPath.item]
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)as? collectionViewCellBooks {
            SwiftLoader.hide()
            cell.initWithBook(book: book)
            return cell
        } else {
            return collectionViewCellBooks()  
        } 
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showImage", sender: self)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    { 
        if segue.identifier == "showImage"
        {
            let vc = segue.destination as! showPdfVC
            vc.book = self.arrayBooks[self.selectedIndexPath.row]
        }
    } 
}
```

The code for `initwithBook` function is

```
func initWithBook(book : BookModel) {
    self.caption.text = book.bookName
    if book.thumbImagePaht == "" {
        let ref = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: book.imageURL)
       let downloadTask =  ref.data(withMaxSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data,error) in
            if error != nil {    
            }else {
                if let imgData = data {
                    if let img = UIImage(data: imgData) {
                        self.imageView.image = img
                        let imageName = book.id+".jpg"
                        let filepath = self.getFilePath(name: imageName)
                        if (try? data?.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: filepath),options: [.atomic])) != nil {
                            self.db.upDateImagePath(id: book.id, imagePath: filepath)
                        }
                        self.stopLoading();
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        downloadTask.observe(.progress) { (snapshot) -> Void in
            // Download reported progress

            let percentComplete = 100 * Double(snapshot.progress!.completedUnitCount)
                / Double(snapshot.progress!.totalUnitCount)

            print(percentComplete)
            // Update the progress indicator
        }

        downloadTask.observe(.success) { (snapshot) -> Void in
            // Download completed successfully
            print("Download Success")
        } 
    } else {
        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: book.thumbImagePaht)
        self.imageView.image = image
        stopLoading();
    }
)
```

Comment: Show the code of `initWithBook` method.

Comment: @NiravD please check the code i added

Answer (score 4):

It's not obvious to me what might be wrong, but I see some issues that may cause problems, and it would be best to fix them:

In any case where you are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` *you need to specify a unique and descriptive identifier*. "cell" is not a good identifier.

Second, when you create a new cell, you need to give it a reuse identifier so that it can be dequeued later.

Third, you didn't follow the naming convention for classes, which is to use TitleCase. It's more difficult to understand your code because of the class you named `collectionViewCellBooks`. It should be named `BookViewCell` or something like that.

Fourth, your example didn't include [a `prepareForReuse` function](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionreusableview/1620141-prepareforreuse) in your Cell class, so I'm going to assume you don't have one. You need to clear the state from the previous use of a cell, since the cell objects are being reused. The default implementation of this function does nothing, so it's up to you to populate it.

```
class BooksViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                          cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let book = arrayBooks[indexPath.item]
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Constants.BookCellReuseIdentifier,
                                                                      for: indexPath) as! BookViewCell
        cell.initWithBook(book: book)
        return cell
    }

    private struct Constants {
        static let BookCellReuseIdentifier = "BookCell"
    }
}

class BookViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        // Remove any state in this cell that may be left over from its previous use.
        self.book = nil
        self.imageView.image = nil
        self.caption = nil
    }

    // Your initWithBook function goes here
}
```

[This is a good tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started) on the use of UICollectionView.

Comment: i am getting an error on this line     cell = collectionViewCellAlbums(reuseIdentifier: Constants.BookCellReuseIdentifier)         "reuceIdentifier do not match any available overload"

Comment: My original answer was based on a UITableViewCell, and it turns out they are different. I updated my answer and linked to a new tutorial.